# Inconsistency with settings values for input field directly in HTML and via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Inconsistency with settings values for input field directly in HTML and via JavaScript.

Here is the example:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <body>
   <input type="text" id="f1" ><br>
   <input type="text" id="f2"  value="123&apos;134"><br>
   <input type="text" id="f3" ><br>
   <input type="text" id="f4" value="123\'134"><br>
   </body>
   </html>​
```

---

```
document.getElementById('f1').value = "123&apos;134";
document.getElementById('f3').value = "123\'134";​
```

Run it here

http://jsfiddle.net/UfaJk/2/

When I set attribute value in HTML, HTML entities are fine, escaped characters are not,
when setting via JavaScript, it is all backwards....

How to handle this?

Comment: Well, it's kinda expected: JS and HTML have different rules for escaping. What exactly are you trying to handle here?

Comment: I want to have single data source for my UI. If I have single data source which is serialized JSON I have to escape quotes and other things to prevent de-serialization to brake. So I have issues to use this data source seamlessly across the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is parsed as HTML, which has particular rules for escaping, such as the string `&apos;` should be interpreted as an apostrophe `'` character.

Likewise, javascript has it's own (and different) escaping rules, such as the string `\'` should be interpreted as an apostrophe `'` character.

Answer (score 0):

Backslash is an escape character in javascipt and in order to output backslash literals, you need to have two backslashes for every single backslash you want to output. 
For example:

```
 document.getElementById('f3').value = "123\\'134";​
```

Hope this helps.